# Installing ClearCase CCRCCLI on Windows

Tags: windows, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm stucked with installation of CCRCCLI on the Windows machine. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263012/clearcase-remote-client-cli), but it still not clear for me.
IBM's [installation manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg24021929) requires setting up variable CCSHARED to the directory of Shared Resources, which can be found in IBM Installation Manager. But I installed CCRC directly from ClearCase server and I had no IBM Installation Manager installed, so I don't know how to find Shared Resources Directory. Later I installed Installation Manager, but it didn't show me any IBM products installed (as expected).
I try to point CCSHARED to plugins subdirectory of CCRC, but it seems to be incorrect.

What it Shared Resources Directory and how to find it on my computer?

Comment: What version of CCRC are you trying to install? On which OS?

Comment: I successfully installed CCRC 7.1 on Windows. The question is about installation of CCRCCLI, not the CCRC itself.

Comment: I have edited the answer. From the documentation, IM is only for CCRC and isn't required for CCRC CLI.

Answer (score 0):

> Later I installed Installation Manager

It is best to uninstall any IBM-ClearCase related product first, then install the [IM (Installation Manager, most recent as possible 1.8.1+)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27025142), then use it to install other Rational projets.

The [CCRC CLI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929) (the tool that provides a command-line interface for ClearCase® Remote Client (CCRC) users to perform commonly used ClearCase® operations over a WAN) needs:

- the CCRC
- Java Runtime Environment (JRE)

  - Version 1.5 (Java 5) for CCRC CLI V 7.1.x.
  - Version 1.6 (Java 6) for CCRC CLI V 8.0.
- the right compatibility between CCRC CLI and the CM Server.
- system requirements [similar to the ones for CCRC](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224586).

If CCRCCLI needs `Shared Folder`, said folder is usually called `IBMIMShared`, at the same level as other IBM products (you can see path examples in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21642949)).
It acts essentially as an Eclipse p2 repository, with its `artifacts.xml` file, `plugins/` and `features/` folders. Installing IM is a good way to create that folder.
However, that `Shared Folder` won't reference the existing CCRC already installed (hence my initial advice).

Comment: tanks for your help, but this is just a citation from CCRCCLI installation manual. Sure I read this and I have all the prerequisites installed (please note tere isn't IM in prerequisites). But this doesn't answer my question. If you have CCRCCLI or CCRC and IM installed on your Windows computer, can you tell me where is Shared Resources directory and what it contains? Maybe based on this info I may locate it on my computer or just create manually?..

Comment: @Andy I did noted that IM isn't a prerequisite and left a comment in that sense on your question. I have edited the question to add more details about the `Shared Folder`.